# If don't see the picture after successful upload django project in heroku server then how can i solve this problems?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have uploaded my django project in heroku server and everything working properly but when i use in settings file DEBUG=False only  this time images are not visible.
If i use DEBUG=True then visible images but if i use DEBUG=False then start problem.

This is Settings file

```
import django_heroku
import os
import environ
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, False),
    ALLOWED_HOSTS=(list),
)
envfile_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env')
environ.Env.read_env(envfile_path)

DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = env('ALLOWED_HOSTS')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

THIRTPARTY_APP = [
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

LOCAL_APP = [
    'protfolio.apps.ProtfolioConfig',
]

INSTALLED_APPS += THIRTPARTY_APP+LOCAL_APP

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000/'
    'http://10.100.68.37:3000/'
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
)



ROOT_URLCONF = 'backapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backapp.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': env('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': env('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': env('DATABASE_PORT')
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfile')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Maybe yon need to run collectstatic? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: Dear sir, already i use this command, but not solved this

Comment: @ Jonas Grumann sir You have others way?

Comment: You *cannot* store user-uploaded files on the Heroku filesystem. You need to upload them to somewhere permanent, like S3.